# JNI: Problems compiling 64-bit native libraries

Tags: java, c, gcc, java-native-interface, native

I compiled a native DLL file on Windows (64-bit) with GCC flags -c and -o Name.dll.

When I did System.load("fullpahhere"), I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: RenderControl.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

If I recompile adding a blank main() method to the C source and removing the -c flag, it then fails with an UnsatisfiedLinkError that says it can't load a 32 bit DLL on a 64 bit machine.

Why is Java calling a DLL with no main method invalid?  Doesn't that ruin the whole point of DLL files and the JNI?

**Update**

I fixed the main() issue.  This GCC invocation setup works:

```
gcc -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\include" -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\include\win32" -shared *.c -o lib.dll
```

I still need to figure out the JVM Architecture problem, however.

Where can I find a MinGW installation that is capable of compilnig 64 bit code?  It seems my standard MinGW install only does 32 bit.

If I can get my hands on that, how do I decide which library to load in Java?  Is there a System property that shows the **JVM arch** (**NOT** the OS arch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the MinGW32 compiler, you cannot produce 64-bit code. This is something that is most likely intentional. Similar issues with other people I quickly looked up seem to suggest that you're trying to use a 32-bit native binary with 64-bit java.

Try compiling with [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) and see if that allays the problem.

There's also the possibility that your library simply isn't in the library path and that it's not being found even though you're giving `System.load` the full path, in which case you should make sure that your DLL is in the correct location for native libraries.

Comment: I was looking at MinGW-w64, and I did download it, but I can't figure out how to install it?  (I got the Windows 64 bit download in a zip file - no installer exe unfortunately...)

Comment: Oh, dang, they only have linux binaries there it seems.

Comment: Also do you know why the DLL is marked as invalid if there is no main()?

Comment: I have a Linux Mint dual boot.  I could try it over there haha.

Comment: If there is a main, I doubt it's even handled as a DLL in this scenario; UnsatisfiedLinkError means the requested library or method cannot be found.

Comment: A smarter solution could be trying with a 32-bit JRE - though, that can be something of a pain on Windows.

Comment: I did.  It comes up with the same "Not a valid Win32 application" error.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/, to download TDM-GCC which gives an easy installation on Windows for MinGW-w64 referenced above.  You can use the following code to generate a 64-bit dll after installint TDM-GCC.

```
"C:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe" -m64 -c -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include\win32" HelloWorld.c
```

It is the "-m64" which makes it 64 bit.  This is run from the same directory as the HelloWorld.c C Code Source File.  This generates the HelloWorld.o C Code Object File in the same directory as run..